# Meaning of "Apache Oozie actions are asynchronous"?

Tags: hadoop, asynchronous, oozie

[This Apache documentations](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.1.2_Actions_Are_Asynchronous) says that Apache Oozie actions are asynchronous. But it also mentions the mechanism to check action status.

> 3.2.1.2 Actions Are Asynchronous
>
> All computation/processing tasks triggered by an action node are executed asynchronously by Oozie. For most types of computation/processing tasks triggered by workflow action, the workflow job has to wait until the computation/processing task completes before transitioning to the following node in the workflow.
>
> The exception is the fs action that is handled as a synchronous action.
>
> Oozie can detect completion of computation/processing tasks by two different means, callbacks and polling.
>
> When a computation/processing tasks is started by Oozie, Oozie provides a unique callback URL to the task, the task should invoke the given URL to notify its completion.
>
> For cases that the task failed to invoke the callback URL for any reason (i.e. a transient network failure) or when the type of task cannot invoke the callback URL upon completion, Oozie has a mechanism to poll computation/processing tasks for completion.

So after an action (say MapReduce job) is triggered, what will happen will it wait till current action completes/fails OR automatically move to next task.
But next task is decided based on current task status

```
<ok to="myNextAction"/>
<error to="errorCleanup"/>
```

So what does it mean by "Actions are Asynchronous" ?

Answer (score 0):

Oozie has main MR job(workflow job) and MRs for each action in workflow.
Workflow job is responsible only for handling workflow(start tasks and wait for completion). Actions are executed in separate MR that means they are asynchronous.